# Mikrotik rb2011 static routing between 2 sites

Tags: mikrotik

I have 2 Mikrotik RB2011 routers. I need for Device on 192.168.3.10 to be able to communicate with device 192.168.2.10 for UDP traffic on port 50000

With the below config I am not able to ping between routers

ie plugged into router 1 cant ping router 2 wan or lan and vice versa

when plugged into the unmanaged switch for the 10.0.0.0/8 i can ping both 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3

Current setup:

```
Router 1 = Benton 
WAN 10.0.0.2 Ether 1
Lan 192.168.2.1 Ether 2
Device 192.168.2.10 Plugged into Ether2

Firewall rules are blank 
Nat rules Blank
Static Routes
#      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          10.0.0.1                  1

1 ADC  10.0.0.0/8         10.0.0.2        WAN Port 1                0

2 ADC  192.168.2.0/24     192.168.2.1     Local Bridge              0

3 A S  192.168.3.1/32                     10.0.0.1                  1


Router 2 = Paducah 
Wan 10.0.0.3 ETHER1
Lan 192.168.3.1 Ether 2
Device 192.168.3.10 plugged into ether 2

Firewall Rules Blank 
Nat Rules Blank 
Static routes
#      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
0 A S       0.0.0.0/0                          10.0.0.1                  1

1 ADC  10.0.0.0/8         10.0.0.3        bridge1                   0
2 A S  192.168.2.1/32                     10.0.0.1                  1
3 ADC  192.168.3.0/24     192.168.3.1     bridge1                   0
```

Comment: Post your configuration. `/interface export` `/ip route export` `/ip firewall export`

Comment: Here is my Config exports https://docs.google.com/document/d/1krZ_1hvfvgdQnqGAJRFZsLLYb6n5Q5mMUCl3zOYMD9M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have made a little progress but have one thing i cant figure out.  I have no NAT Just the static routes.  from pc1 i can ping 192.168.2.1 , 2.10 and 2.100 as well as 3.1, 3.10 and 3.100.    From pc2 i can ping 192.168.3.10,, 3.100.. 2.1,, 2.10 and 2.100 but not 3.1??